# converting rownames back to column format

Tags: r

I want to convert rownames in my dataframe into first column

Example intput:

```
                                        y
species1                         3.783584
species2                         3.696341
species3                         3.968285
```

Desired output:

```
       x                                y
species1                         3.783584
species2                         3.696341
species3                         3.968285
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using

```
df$x <- rownames(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the row names to a new column:

```
df$x <- rownames(df)
df <- df[,c("x", "y")]
```

The second step is only necessary if, for some reason, you care about column order.

If you also want to revert the row names to the numerical sequence they would have by default, you may do so via:

```
rownames(df) <- seq(nrow(df))
```

Comment: but that doesn't preserve the the column order. when I do it, it puts column x after column y and still leaves the 1st column row names as is

Comment: @user3683803 I didn't know this was an issue for you.  I updated my answer.

Comment: I get an Error: undefined columns selected

Comment: Then I think your code has a problem.  My answer should be working.

Comment: i tried again and now it has the order I want (x in first column and y in second column) but it preserves the row names which i want removed

Comment: I gave you an option for changing the row names.

Comment: can you suggest how I should word my question because your solution is not what i want and it seems like you understand my question

Comment: OK...if you _don't_ want the original row names to be there, then you may overwrite them with anything, provided all the names are unique.